# Error pop up doesn't close in Oracle Forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

I am using some pl/sql code in post-forms-commit trigger in oracle form.
I am trying to display error message by using

```
FND_MESSAGE.SET_NAME('ABC', 'ABC_ERROR_MSG');
APP_EXCEPTION.RAISE_EXCEPTION;
```

This error pops up when one validation fails.

Now the issue is that whenever this error message is generated in a popup window,it does not close.
When I click ok button it appears again and again.

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

There is some problem with your exception handling.  Without seeing the code it's difficult to be specific but it seems as though your code keeps returning to the validation point instead of moving on.

One thing: `APP_EXCEPTION.RAISE_EXCEPTION` is for stored procedures.  If you are calling Forms PL/SQL code you should be using `RAISE FORM_TRIGGER_FAILURE;` .  [Find out more.](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18727_01/doc.121/e12897/T302934T307517.htm)